# Possible exceptions during FTP operations in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I need to delete some files that are not required from FTP using C#. Can someone tell me the possible exceptions that can occur during the entire operation like wrong credentials or FTP connection lost during deletion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see FtpStatusCode.*. You can catch it as a generic WebException, but then detect if it is entailed in the aforementioned.

Here is a list of generic FTP Server Returns:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes

Here are specific .NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpstatuscode.aspx